# cloudfoundry multi node push

Tags: push, cloud-foundry, vmc

Can you create application instances on multiple nodes with a single push command. If so, what is the process of that? Would you create multiple DEA instances?

So for a configuration like this would a "vmc push appname --instances 4" create:
REST_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|            |            |            |           
DEA    DEA    DEA    DEA 
App1  App2     App3     App4

Or do you have to push instances manually to each DEA node?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command as you've listed it, yes, it will basically cause your application to be started "at once" on 4 DEAs. You don't need to run vmc push for each instance - in fact, you can't use vmc to individually address a DEA.

Once a DEA is running your app, you can have the app show e.g. the IP address and port the DEA is running on by interrogating the VCAP environment.